# Update a props is updating the parent state?

Tags: reactjs

In my App component, I pass a props called `parameters` to a Child component. The props value is a state element of App.

```
<App
    <Child parameters={this.state.x}
/>
```

Is it normal that if I set a value to the *parameters* props in the child component, it's updating the state of the App component ?

Execute this in Child... :

```
this.props.parameters.foo='bar';
```

Will update the App state :

```
console.log(this.state.parameters.foo) //display 'bar'
```

Comment: It is a reference, correct? IMO anything on `this.props` should be treated as read-only.

Comment: Same for me, it's normal that it is modified by reference. Otherwise, you should not mutate the props.

Comment: All right, so props are reference, not values, didn't know that. I agree with you, it's ugly to change the state parent with the props in a child component. Best way is to pass a function via props to the child who update the parent state.

Comment: This [React document](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow) on data binding would help catch the point.